# ggplot containing two different groupings returns empty plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

this is my sample dataframe.
I am going to show different grp s with different color and different subgrp s with different line types. and shows these two as legends.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date = rep(c("Jan-2010", "Feb-2010", "Mar-2010", "Apr-2010" ,"Dec-2009"),each=5),
                 grp = c(LETTERS[1:5], LETTERS[2:6], LETTERS[1:5],LETTERS[3:7], LETTERS[1:5]),
                 subgrp = c("x","x","x","y","y","x","x","y","y","y","x","x","x","y","y",
                            "x","y","y","y","y","x","x","x","y","y"),
                 value = sample(4:10, 25, replace=TRUE))


df
       date grp subgrp value
1  Jan-2010   A      x     7
2  Jan-2010   B      x    10
3  Jan-2010   C      x     6
4  Jan-2010   D      y     4
5  Jan-2010   E      y     5
6  Feb-2010   B      x     7
7  Feb-2010   C      x     5
8  Feb-2010   D      y     4
9  Feb-2010   E      y     6
10 Feb-2010   F      y     7
11 Mar-2010   A      x     8
12 Mar-2010   B      x    10
13 Mar-2010   C      x     7
14 Mar-2010   D      y    10
15 Mar-2010   E      y     5
16 Apr-2010   C      x     4
17 Apr-2010   D      y     9
18 Apr-2010   E      y     7
19 Apr-2010   F      y     5
20 Apr-2010   G      y     5
21 Dec-2009   A      x     6
22 Dec-2009   B      x     8
23 Dec-2009   C      x     6
24 Dec-2009   D      y     8
25 Dec-2009   E      y     9
```

but even for grouping, it returns an empty plot.

```
df %>%

  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=date,
                y=value,
                color=grp))
```

[image]

I would appreciate any hint or help to fix this.

Comment: Use `aes(date, value, color = grp, group = grp)`. This happens because ggplot needs to decide what points should be connected together, i.e. what the groups are. By default, the groups are just whatever aesthetics are discrete, in your case both `date` and `grp`. But you only want to group by `grp`, so you override the default.

Comment: Thanks. right but if I assign grp to both color and group arguments how can I change the line types according to subgrp variable

Comment: Also note that this why you get the message _"geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"_

Comment: Sorry, missed that. `aes(date, value, color = grp, lty = subgrp, group = interaction(grp, subgrp))`. (By the way, if your dates were of the `Date` class and not a character vector, it would work out of the box. In your example e.g. Dec 2009 comes after Apr 2010.)

Comment: lty in aes! cool thank you.